# Weird singling out item in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

When i select an item in navigationDrawer i get very confusing behavior. It looks like this [here you can see a screenshot, i singled out the selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToRiy.png)

I want to get a behavior [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ofed.png) (like in navigationDrawer activity which you can create from android studio)
I tried to apply a theme

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/activated_color</item>
</style>
```

But it doesnt helps, the relust is the same, here is some code:
navigationDrawer in main activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:theme="@style/TextAppearance"
    android:id="@+id/nav_viewInMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

The item code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw_list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_43"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorForMainText"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The app bar code(maybe its matters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarSubtitleAppearance"
    app:theme="@style/CoolTheme"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleAppearance"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<style name="CoolTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

The colorPrimary is #efefef
And the main style from manifest

```
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPopup</item>
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
```

The colorPopup is #FFFFFF

Answer (score 0):

Create your NavigationDrawer Activity like this-

right click on activity -> New -> Activity -> Naigation Drawer Activity.

This will solve your problem!

Comment: But i already created an activity with NavigationDrawer, i dont need another one

Comment: Did u created it this way? The way I mentioned

Comment: No, i created it by myself and it was working like default before i changed style in manifest

Comment: Delete it and do it this way....which i mentioned.....that is a stable and well prepared NavigationActivity....just delete the way you created and do it as i said...will be solved

Comment: if u dont want to do that then use
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight"</item> in the CustomToolbarStyle of the manisfest and also remove the background attribute from it.

Comment: Okay, i got it, this happens because of conflict with android:background in style, which i use in manifest, maybe i shoud move this style to activity?

Comment: Sorry but i cant do this, i have less than 15 reputation